# aggregate value used where an integer was expected

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 50000000

// The following is a struct in C.
// This paradigm allows for arbitrary data to be stored
// in a structured way. This also allows for multiple
// parameters to be passed to a thread function.
// You should use this struct with the add_arrays
// function when running using threads.
struct data {
  int* a;
  int* b;
  int* c;
  int start_idx; // Where the thread should start in an array
};

void* add_arrays(void* arg) {
    
    // Elements from the thread_data struct can be accessed here
    // Ex thread_data.a

    // @TODO
    // Split the work of c[i] = a[i] + b[i] between two threads.
    // HINT: Work should be split half-and-half. Use start_idx
    // to coordinate this.
    // +5
    struct data thread_data = *(struct data*) arg;
    int* a = thread_data.a;
    int* b = thread_data.b;
    int* c = thread_data.c;
    int start_idx = thread_data.start_idx;
    int end_idx = start_idx + ARRAY_SIZE/2;
    for (int i = start_idx; i < end_idx; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* rand_init(void* arg) {
    int range_start = 0;
    int range_end = 9;

    // @TODO
    // Fill an array with random variables using a thread.
    // Remember to use rand_r and not rand. You will also need to
    // change how the random seed is calculated such that it is unique
    // for each thread. For more details, see the assignment PDF or README.
    // HINT: The input parameter should be an array, not a struct.
    // +5
    int* a = (int*) arg;
    unsigned int seed = time(NULL) ^ (unsigned int) (uintmax_t) pthread_self();
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE/2; i++) {
        a[i] = rand_r(&seed) % 10;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    // @TODO
    // Allocate the source arrays (a, b, c)
    // a and b are the source arrays.
    // c is the result storage array.
    // c[i] should equal a[i] + b[i]
    // Make sure to error check.
    // +1
    int *a, *b, *c;

    //allocating space for arrays and error checking
    a = (int*)(malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(int)));
    if (a == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    b = (int*)(malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(int)));
    if (b == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        free(a);
        exit (1);
    }
    c = (int*)(malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(int)));
    if (c == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        free(a);
        free(b);
        exit(1);
    }

    // @TODO
    // Create two pthreads and initialize a and b with
    // random numbers using both threads. The full operation
    // should be timed and the period printed.
    // +4
    clock_t start_time, end_time;
    double execution_time;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;



    start_time = clock();
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, rand_init, a);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, rand_init, b);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    end_time = clock();

    execution_time = ((double)(end_time - start_time))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    execution_time = execution_time*1000;
    printf("Total init time: %.2f ms\n", execution_time);


    // @TODO
    // Define and prepare two structs for each thread.
    // The structs should contain data relevent to the add operation.
    // +2
    struct data data1 = {a, b, c, 0};
    struct data data2 = {a, b, c, ARRAY_SIZE/2};

    // @TODO
    // Reuse your pthreads from earlier and time your add_arrays function
    // as it runs on both threads.
    // +2

    start_time = clock();
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, add_arrays, &data1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, add_arrays, &data2);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    end_time = clock();
    execution_time = ((double)(end_time - start_time))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    execution_time = execution_time*1000;

    // @TODO
    // Print out the first 10 elements of the result array and the final
    // period for the add_arrays threaded function runs.
    // +2
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //first 10 elements
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\nTotal add time: %.2f ms\n", execution_time); //add function time taken

    // Free the memory
    // +1

    free (a);
    free (b);
    free (c);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Q2.c: In function 'rand_init':
Q2.c:58:5: error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected
     unsigned int seed = time(NULL) ^ (unsigned int) (uintmax_t) pthread_self();
     ^~~~~~~~
Q2.c:60:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand_r' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         a[i] = rand_r(&seed) % 10;
```

I am getting the following errors in c. Using docker to run linux pthreads. All this is very complicated to me. I am not sure how we can use threads to generate random numbers.

I got this line from chatGPT
`unsigned int seed = time(NULL) ^ (unsigned int) (uintmax_t) pthread_self();`

But no matter what solution I follow the code wont run. I wish to know if this is due to a error in my code or my development environment.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I got this line from chatGPT" That is probably the source of your problem. And I think that current policies (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) mean that your post is off-topic. I close-vote as "not about programming" because you describe a problem of understanding a conversation with an AI, which is not meant to provide working code. You can try asking ChatGPT "Did you try to compile that? What error messages and warnings did you get from the compiler? If it did compile, what test cases did you apply? Did they pass?"

Comment: I would be impressed to see coherent and trurhful answers. What I expect is "Yes, it compiles fine." as a ChatGPT answer. Which is of course looking like a good answer, but essentially an obvious lie, because you already proved it to be not compilable. And that summarizes nicely the problem with ChatGPT and a major reason for banning it here.

Comment: "I wish to know if this is due to a error in my code or my development environment." Probably not. I assume that your IDE is fine and I hope that your code is OK. The code provided by ChatGPT is the most questionable and unreliable one in this chain. Do you confuse "my code" with "code provided by a rountinely lying text generator with the goal to produce good-looking answers which are however pure shuffle of good looking non-code text fragments"?

Comment: Regarding `rand_r`, how do you compile and which compiler is used? gcc in strict C mode will remove non-standard functions (identifiers really) from standard headers.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

- missing `#include <stdio.h>`
- in the line `unsigned int seed = time(NULL) ^ (unsigned int) (uintmax_t) pthread_self();` you cast the return value of `pthread_self()` as an integer: this might be causing the warning. Try using this instead:

  ```
   unsigned int seed = time(NULL) ^ (unsigned int)(uintptr_t)arg;
  ```

  Alternately, you could make the `seed` part of the thread `data` and initialize it in `main()` using `srand(time(NULL))` and `rand()`.
- using `clock()` to measure the elapsed time in a multi-thread program might not be meaningful.  Using `gettimeofday()` seems more reliable.
- you get an error for `rand_r()`: this is very surprising as this function is part of POSIX, declared in `<stdlib.h>`.  You could try using `rand()` to check if the program compiles.  Yet using `rand_r()` seems more appropriate, so fix issue should be fixed.
- the expression using `range_start` and `range_end` should be:

  ```
  a[i] = range_start + rand_r(&seed) % (range_end + 1 - range_start);
  ```

  note however that this expression may introduce a small bias which is insignificant for this test program.